# Geopandas not displaying map

Tags: python, maps, geopandas, shapefile

I'm new to programming and I'm learning on my own so I'm sorry for any confusions...
I need to make this map with frequencies and I have a shapefile, I merged the shapefile to the dbf file so I had the info on the states I needed. Then, I merged that to my excel file which has the data needed to get the map "coloured" and did the plot, the thing is my map is not showing, it's blank! I really don't know what to do, I've tried everything I could find online...

I share my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

proj4_string = (
    "+proj=lcc +lat_1=17.5 +lat_2=29.5 +lat_0=12 +lon_0=-102 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 "
    "+a=6378137 +rf=298.257222101 +units=m +no_defs"
)
mx = gpd.read_file("/content/enti.shp")
mx.crs = proj4_string
mx.plot()
print(mx)
print(mx.columns)

# Read the Excel data
excel_path = '/content/BH2020.xlsx'
df20 = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
merged_data = pd.merge(mx, df20, left_on='CVE_ENT_x', right_on='Entidades', how='left')
print(merged_data)

# Create the plot
merged_data.plot(column='TOTALES', cmap='Reds', linewidth=0.8, edgecolor='0.8', legend=True)

# Set the title
plt.title('Brucelosis en México 2020')

# Show the plot
plt.show()[enter link description here][1]
```

This is my final result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKc6Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

The first step thing I would do is to remove redundant code from the script, possibly that already solves the problem.

Redundant pieces of code:

1. you can remove all specific code regarding the dbf file. The `mx = gpd.read_file("/content/enti.shp")` call already reads the .dbf. If you put `print(mx)` or `print(mx.columns)` after reading the .shp you'll see that.
2. because you read the shp again after setting the crs with `mx.crs = proj4_string`, the crs will be lost again, because setting the crs like that doesn't change anything to the file on disk. So, you need to remove the second `mx = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)` as well.
3. all the duplicated import statements don't help either for readability, so they should also be removed.

EDIT: I had a look with mocked data and the merge and plot code seems to be doing the trick. So, the issue seems to be in the data.

Script with mocked data:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely

proj4_string = (
    "+proj=lcc +lat_1=17.5 +lat_2=29.5 +lat_0=12 +lon_0=-102 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 "
    "+a=6378137 +rf=298.257222101 +units=m +no_defs"
)
mx = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data={"CVE_ENT_x": ["Brussels", "Amsterdam"]},
    geometry=[shapely.box(0, 0, 10, 10), shapely.box(20, 0, 30, 10)],
)
mx.crs = proj4_string
df20 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Entidades": ["Brussels", "Amsterdam"], "TOTALES": [10, 20]})

merged_data = pd.merge(mx, df20, left_on="CVE_ENT_x", right_on="Entidades", how="left")

# Create the plot
merged_data.plot(
    column="TOTALES", cmap="Reds", linewidth=0.8, edgecolor="0.8", legend=True
)

# Set the title
plt.title("Brucelosis en México 2020")

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I edited my code and my question, it's still not showing but it's much easier to see where the mistake might be! This is my colab link... might help? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z8vSaEBrCEjBvzWT6d9rPaad-8Ks_NQL#scrollTo=do3f7ZnoqsZ_

Comment: I don't have access to the colab project. I had another look with mocked data, and the merge + plot code seems to work, so it seems that there is an issue with the data. Best that you taak another good look if all the fields are containing the right data. Possibly there is an encoding issue with the shapefile.